# Return data from multiple tables using LINQ Method Syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have got problem with return data from my database. In my database are three tables: Customer, Activity and CustomerActivity. I want to return activities data for specific customer and with specific type activity. I wrote query but it doesn't work exactly as I wish. Here is my code and tables. Thank you for advices.

```
var activities = db.Join(db.CustomerActivities, a => a.ActivityID, ca =>ca.CustomerActivityID, (a, ca) => new { Activity = a, CustomerActivity = ca })
    .Where(a => a.CustomerActivity.customer.CustomerID == id && a.Activity.TypeActivityID == typeActivity)
    .Select(m => new ActivityMV()
    {
        ActivityID = m.Activity.ActivityID,
        Name = m.Activity.Name,
        DateOfActivity = m.Activity.DateOfActivity,
        Desc = m.Activity.Desc
    })
    .ToList();


public class CustomerActivity
{
    public int CustomerActivityID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int ActivityID { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Activity activity { get; set; }
}
public class Activity
{
    public int ActivityID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string DateOfActivity { get; set; }
    public string TypeActivityID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection <CustomerActivity> customerActivities { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "I wrote query but it doesn't work exactly as I wish." What is your actual result vs. your expected result?

Comment: There is no need of joins (`db.Join(...)` is not a valid construct anyway). Start the query from `db.CustomerActivities` and simply use `CustomerActivity` navigation properties (`Customer` and `Activity`) in `Where` and `Select` expressions.

Comment: To method I send two parameters: customer Id and type of activity. I want to get all activities for customer with specific type. I add that same data for two users and once in two different cases I get two diffrent results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var activities = db.CustomerActivities
.Where(ca => ca.CustomerID == id && ca.Activity.TypeActivityID == typeActivity)
.Select(ca => new ActivityMV()
{
    ActivityID = ca.ActivityID,
    Name = ca.Activity.Name,
    DateOfActivity = ca.Activity.DateOfActivity,
    Desc = ca.Activity.Desc
})
.ToList();
```

Comment: Ohh, it works perfectly. One trifle: `.Select(ca => new ActivityMV()` Thanks!